# Equivalent to "shorten <=" for intermediate points

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Halo everybody,

I try to plot a data set using tikz & pgf. I want that the points in the plot are connected, but the line shouldn't touch the points. I can achieve this for the first and the last point by using `shorten <=` and `shorten >=` but the line runs still directly all other points. How can I achieve a gap around each point?

Here a minimalist example of my current attempt:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    grid=major
]
\addplot [mark=*, line width=1pt, shorten <= 5pt, shorten >= 5pt] table {
    10 10
    20 30
    30 25
    40 31
    50 32
    60 45
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `mark options` like `mark options={draw=white,}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
%\tikzset{every mark/.append style={draw=white}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    grid=major
]
\addplot [mark=*,mark options={draw=white,}, line width=1pt] table {
    10 10
    20 30
    30 25
    40 31
    50 32
    60 45
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `mark options={draw=white,line width=3pt,scale=2}` we get,

[image]

Adjust parameters as suitable for you.

If you need custom `o` mark, you can define one

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{h}{
    \fill[white](0,0) circle (1.5\pgfplotmarksize);
    \draw (0,0) circle (\pgfplotmarksize);
}
```

Change the `1.5` here as desired.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
%\tikzset{every mark/.append style={draw=white}}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{h}{
    \fill[white](0,0) circle (1.5\pgfplotmarksize);
    \draw (0,0) circle (\pgfplotmarksize);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    grid=major
]
\addplot [mark=h,mark options={line width=0.6pt},line width=1pt] table {
    10 10
    20 30
    30 25
    40 31
    50 32
    60 45
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I have a second data serious, where I would like to use `mark=o`. But when I use `mark=o` there are no circles visible, any idea?

Comment: @Zünni Because it is drawn `white`. See the update.